# UML class diagram web service

Tags: service, uml

How do I draw a class in UML that uses a web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use [WSDL (Web Services Description Language) UML profile](http://webservices.xml.com/lpt/a/1259) with the appropriate WSDL stereotypes.

That would give for example:

```
--------------------
| <<wsdl:service>> |
--------------------
|   MyWebService   |
--------------------
|                  |
--------------------
|                  |
--------------------
{URI="/MyWebService"}
```

---

A full UML example involving many components of a web service would be:

[image]
<sub>(source: [xml.com](http://webservices.xml.com/2003/08/05/graphics/CompleteUML.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a sequence diagram, with client and service instances, where the client makes the call to the service.  If the request is synchronous, you'll see the return come back to the client; if not, there's no return.

Answer (score 0):

I would have draw the web service as an interface.

I would put a boundary around the web service to indicate it's located outside my system boundary.