# UML diagram for web service dependencies

Tags: uml

I am attempting to draw a UML diagram for the our web service dependencies. I need to break down how all the projects in our solution interact with different web services.

My initial thought what to use Communication Diagram but that did't seem like the right choice when I looked at some examples. Does anyone have any suggestions? Is there an industry standard? I did see[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428377/uml-class-diagram-web-service) here as well but I am asking what TYPE of diagram do I choose.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like according to [this](http://www.altova.com/umodel/uml-architecture-diagrams.html) I should be using a Package Diagram